# React CDN, is there a way to load the script with async?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I can go to the site https://reactjs.org/docs/cdn-links.html, what i find there is this CDN:

```
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

I am wondering if there is a way you can load the script async like any other javascript and place it in the 
like this:

```
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js" async></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js" async></script>
```

The script I am trying to load after this does also have async in it:

```
<script src ="index.js" async></script>
```

But somehow it's not loading. And i am geting:

```
index.js:3 Uncaught ReferenceError: React is not defined
```

If i remove the async from the CDN everything works.

Comment: what happens when you do? (obviously with a space between `"` and `async` (not sure if that's 100% required, but, lets strive to write proper HTML :p )

Comment: Does not work, just get this error message when i try to index.js:3 Uncaught ReferenceError: React is not defined
    at index.js:3 But workes after i remove async

Comment: Yes you are right, I added space between " and async still the same results tho.

Comment: because your code is trying to access `React` before the library has loaded ... you need to somehow wait for those async scripts to load before using them

Comment: You can, but not recommended, because then you'd need to have an extra check to detect if react is fully loaded before trying to execute your own script (which depends on react) so you're not gaining any performance

Comment: It's strange as i put it in the <head> and should be loaded first before the body? I can maybe use  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => alert("DOM ready!")); and check it this way?

Comment: `should be loaded first before the body` - not if it's `async` - that's the whole point of the async attribute

Comment: You should only use async for scripts that are standalone and where it doesn't matter if it gets loaded 10min after everything else as a matter of speaking. Async has no order, so having two scripts with async could mean that the second one gets loaded first, then the first one, and if your second one depends on the first one, you'll run into issues. You could use defer to for the scripts or just put all your scripts at the end of the body to have a faster first paint.

Comment: Yes before i always did just put them at the end of the body but this changed me  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/436411/where-should-i-put-script-tags-in-html-markup but i will try defer and do it in a order.

Comment: Hm it's strange even with defer it did not work for me maybe it has something to do with crossorigin?

Comment: Nvm i forgot to put defer on the other script i was loading after the CDN, now it works :)